# May I analyze this kind of data with ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have the following kind of experimental setup. There are two different tasks (say A and B) the participants are performing. Each task is performed thrice (three times) by each participant. There is one measurement per performed task. In summary, I have data such as

```
Task Subject Score
A    1       10
A    1       20
A    1       15
B    2       5
B    2       10
B    2       30
...  ...     ...
```

I am not entirely sure which test to use. Clearly, the observations within each task are correlated, since each participant does the same thing several times.

Based on searching the web, I think this should be analyzed using some kind of ANOVA. Which test is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to analyse your data but I think a first approach to do it in `R` could be to add another column called Trial (3 levels).

```
Task Subject Trial Score
A    1       1     10
A    1       2     20
A    1       3     15
B    2       1     5
...  ...     ...   ...
```

Then using the `lmer` function from the `lme4` package you could create a model using your trial as random term:

```
mod1 <- lmer(Score ~ Task * Subject + (1|Trial), data=your_data)
```

Then for the ANOVA, you could use the `Anova` function from the `car` package on your model:

```
car::Anova(mod1)
```

Finally, you would have to check if your model meet the assumptions. I believe this should be an appropriate way to analyse your data.

Comment: I should add that since your explanatory variables are categories, yes you can most likely analyse your data with ANOVA. The idea behind adding the trial column and run a linear mixed-effects model is to deal with the fact that your participants performed each task 3 times.

Comment: One more thing, you should probably define each of your response variable as categorical using something like this code `your_data$Task<-as.factor(your_data$Task)`

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment I meant "... each of your explanatory variable..."